# Getting only 1 as row count in php

Tags: php, mysqli

Is there any mistake in this code ? or  my error is somewhere else .

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","sajan")
or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");   
$sql_count = "SELECT count(*) FROM user";
$result = $conn->query($sql_count);
$total_row = $result_count->num_rows;
```

Comment: Your query returns exactly one row, the first column of which is the count of rows in the table. You need to `fetch` the row and read the column.

Comment: because you are calculating count, obviously you will get a single row containing the count

Answer (score 1):

Yes count will aggregate and give you only 1 value,You need to do this instead

```
$sql_count = "SELECT count(*) as total FROM user";
$result = $conn->query($sql_count);
$arrayresult = $result->fetch_array();
echo $arrayresult['total]
```

Answer (score 0):

if you need both data and results count you must use this

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","sajan")
or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");   
$sql_count = "SELECT * FROM user";
$result = $conn->query($sql_count);
$total_row = $result->num_rows;
```

if you just need the count rahul solution is good and optimal that is

```
$sql_count = "SELECT count(*) as total FROM user";
$result = $conn->query($sql_count);
$arrayresult = $result->fetch_array();
echo $arrayresult['total]
```

Answer (score -3):

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","sajan")
or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");   
$sql_count = "SELECT count(*) FROM user";
$result = $conn->query($sql_count);
$total_row = $result->num_rows;
```

will do the trick, you're referencing `$result_count;` which is not set.

Comment: you point it right but it still will result a single row. because its calculating the count not data in query